# CompileError: UnimplementedFeatureError: Encoding type "struct A.Params memory" not yet implemented

Tags: solidity

I am hitting a deadend and I hope I can get some enlightenment.

In one of the contract, Pool.sol I have a storage state variable defined as:

```
struct PoolParam {
        string xyz;
        string yzy;
        address[] tokens;
        uint[] balances;
        uint[] tokenWeights;
  }

PoolParam public PoolInfo;
```

Then, PoolInfo is updated as information is gathered throughout the life cycle of the contract:

```
PoolInfo.tokens.push(address(0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2));
PoolInfo.balances.push(300);
PoolInfo.tokenWeights.push(2);
```

After update is completed, this variable is passed into a function which is owned by another contract Factory.sol:

```
Factory.Create(PoolInfo);
```

The signature of Create in Factory.sol is:

```
function Create(
        Pool.PoolParam calldata poolParams
    )
        external
        returns (newPool)
    {
```

I then I got a compilation error:

CompileError: UnimplementedFeatureError: Encoding type "struct Pool.PoolParam  memory" not yet implemented.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please post the code which reproduces this problem, and not some hypothetical example with a bunch of other compilation errors.

Comment: @goodvibration updated.

Comment: Currently, `public` and `external` functions cannot take a struct as input or return a struct as output. You need to "decompose" it (i.e., pass its fields and/or return its fields).

Comment: I'm not sure what your function returns, because the code in your question says `returns (newPool)`, which doesn't even compile!

Comment: But it definitely needs to take `string xyz, string yzy, address[] memory tokens, uint[] memory balances, uint[] memory tokenWeights` as input.

Comment: I don't think thats true. newPool is just a contract. If you want to look at the code before my modification here it is: https://github.com/balancer-labs/configurable-rights-pool/blob/master/contracts/CRPFactory.sol#L50  Basically, if you can call the newCrp from a different contract, then that would achieve what I need.

Comment: @goodvibration you are right - I need pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;

Comment: When you don't specify in your question what `newPool` is, the code doesn't compile (and for a different reason than what your question is all about)!

Answer (score 1):

```
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;
```

define this on the top of the file. It will solve.